grub boot menu doesn't appear after editing on Ubuntu 24.10
i did some edit on Ubuntu 24.10 following this question and this question
I edited grub with sudo nano /etc/default/grub following by the command sudo update-grub
The edit was:
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || ec>
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

After I rebooted the system the boot menu or grub menu didn't appear and it went straight to Ubuntu 24.10. Now I cannot log in to my other operating system. I don't know what I did wrong. What can I do so that the grub boot menu appears again from which I can choose the operating system that I want to use?

@mpboden This question is not a duplicate of your linked question because the problem in this question is caused by an error in the grub file in the line that starts with GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR

@karel Well, I thought it was related to his configuration setting: GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden. Shouldn’t this be deleted or set to menu?

@mpboden Yes, it should also be changed from GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu.

The issue with the  grub file is caused by a truncated line. This line is cut off after ec> which should be echo Ubuntu`
The correct line should be:
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`

Note the pair of matching ` characters after GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR
The line the says GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden hides the GRUB boot menu entirely and only shows it if the user presses a key during boot. Change this line to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu.
After editing /etc/default/grub run sudo update-grub to regenerate the GRUB configuration.
